# Regular expression in python does not match

Tags: python, regex

I'm doing regular expression on python. I spend much time to fix and to know why the regular expression doesn't work or match. I  post the text and my code here. May I know what is wrong with my code:

The text is :

```
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 writev(25, [{"\0\225ub'\375[\340\244\6/", 11}, {"\4", 1}, 
{"Id before\0", 17}, {"Id\0", 10}], 4) = 39
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 getuid()           = 10168
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 getuid()           = 10168
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 ioctl(8, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fc0656648) = 0
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 ioctl(8, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fc0656648) = 0
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 fstat(33, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(10, 62), 
...}) = 0
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 fstat(33, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(10, 62), 
...}) = 0
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 ioctl(33, ASHMEM_GET_SIZE, 0) = 84
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 dup(33)            = 34
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 close(33)          = 0
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 dup(34)            = 33
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 fstat(33, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(10, 62), 
...}) = 0
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 ioctl(33, ASHMEM_GET_SIZE, 0) = 84
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 mmap(NULL, 84, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 33, 0) = 
0x7d517db000
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 fstat(33, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(10, 62),...}) = 0
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 ioctl(33, ASHMEM_GET_SIZE, 0) = 84
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 fstat(34, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(10, 62), 
 ...}) = 0
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 fstat(34, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(10, 62),...}) = 0
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 ioctl(34, ASHMEM_GET_SIZE, 0) = 84
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 close(34)          = 0
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 getuid()           = 10168
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 writev(25, [{"\0\225ub'\375[\260y\3274", 11}, {"\4", 1}, 
{"After\0", 16}, {"eb41e1a15da0b8ee\0", 17}], 4) = 45
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 ioctl(8, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fc0656ee8) = 0
[pid 30101] 04:15:46 ioctl(8, BINDER_WRITE_READ, 0x7fc0656ee8) = 0
```

and here is my code:

```
import re
text = open('textfile.txt').read()
pid= str(30101)
if re.findall(r"^.* " + pid +"] \d\d:\d\d:\d\d getuid()^.*" + pid +"]\d\d:\d\d:\d\d ioctl\(8\, BINDER_WRITE_READ\, 0x7fc0656648\)^.*" + pid +"] \d\d:\d\d:\d\d fstat\(33\, \{st_mode=S_IFCHR\|0666\, st_rdev=makedev\(10\, 62\)\, 
...\}\).*", text, re.M):
   print 'found a match!'
else:
   print 'no match'
```

Comment: Try [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) (you have to choose the correct regex engine).

Comment: @Bakuriu thanks, I didn't know about this website. it is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try to start small when developing regular expressions. Some characters (like `[`, `]`, `(`, `)`, ...) have a special meaning. If you want to literally match these characters, you need to escape them by appending a `\` in front of the character.

A simplified version of your regex using escapes:

```
import re
text = open('textfile.txt').read()
pid= str(30101)
print re.findall(r"^.* " + pid + "\] \d\d:\d\d:\d\d getuid\(\)", text, re.M)
```

Produces the following output:

```
['[pid 30101] 04:15:46 getuid()', '[pid 30101] 04:15:46 getuid()', '[pid 30101] 04:15:46 getuid()']
```

I would suggest to read the python docs of the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module which explains the syntax and then expanding your regular expression step-by-step.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Feix Thanks for the help. your hit is very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all guys, I've tried regex101.com very helpful and a good to build my regex in python. I tried creating my regular expression, but I faced a problem. There are two dup() matching at 10 and 12 lines. Every time, my regular expression match the dup() that at line 12 but I want to find the next first match which at 10 line. I wanna the match start from top to bottom is not from bottom to top. 
I feel the problem because of [\s\S]+. 
do I use it correctly?

Here is my try: 
https://regex101.com/r/5WpzKV/3